# EntityEntry<ApplicationUser> does not contain a definition for 'Reference'

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

How do I specify in `EF7` that I wish to explicitly load the reference property Subject of my ApplicationUser entity? In EF6 the following is defined in the namespace `System.Data.EntityFramework.Infrastructure`:

```
public DbReferenceEntry<TEntity, TProperty> Reference<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> navigationProperty) where TProperty : class;
```

So this code:

```
public async override Task<ApplicationUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(System.Threading.CancellationToken))
    {
        var user = await base.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        this.Context.Entry(user).Reference(u => u.Subjects).Load();
        return user;
    }
```

gives an exception

```
EntityEntry<ApplicationUser> does not contain a definition for 'Reference'.
```

Where is this extension method defined in `EF7`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent yet in EF7 as of beta7.

To include related entities, use eager loading with the `.Include()` method in your query.

`context.User.Include(u => u.Subjects)`